# What's the best way of making sticky vertical navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment, navbar

I am about to code my portfolio and I want a vertical navigation like this in this website: http://pixelhint.com/demo/magnetic/index.html

I saw others do it with JQuery but it was horizontal. I couldn't find any solution on how to do it if the navigation was to be vertical.

I would appreciate any help. I like the idea of using jquery plugins but I think it would be better if I code it from scratch. I just need an idea on how to do it.

Comment: if you check the web Inspector Tool you can see what CSS used for that `min-height: 100%;` and `position: fixed;` are playing major Role here.

Comment: I know that. But I've read that sticky navbars should use JQuery/Jscript. So I was wondering what's the use of it or is it the best way of doing it.

Comment: what you are looking  can achieve just a CSS. then why use JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are good with css only in this case

What you need to do basically, is to create an element with a fixed position.
Then just add some side space (padding/margin) onto your main content element

http://jsfiddle.net/PZRqY/

```
<aside>navigation content</aside>
<main>the main content</main>

aside {

   position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:300px;//a value by which you need to add a offset onto your content element
    height:100%;

}

main {
    padding-left:300px;//offset so as the content is not overlayed by the navigation
}
```

Comment: I thought you need jscript/jquery for it to be fully functional? I guess not then for vertical ones? I've read some articles on how to make horizontal sticky navbars and they were all talking about jscript/jquery incorporated with their codes. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: It depends on what you read. There might have been some additional funcionality, like toggling the navigation when scrolling, however a thing you wanted is easily accomplished by css. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily append html block like this:

```
<div class="fix-left-panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and new css rule:

```
.fix-left-panel {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```